# Are Adobe Typekit fonts "free" to use?

Tags: fonts, creative-cloud, font-licensing, typekit

Being a CC subscriber, is it ok to use Adobe Typekit fonts for commercial purposes?
And are there any other notable T's and C's one should be aware of when using Typekit fonts?

Comment: DONT use this service.. it forces everyone to buy the product.. terrible to have clients not able to see it until they sign up and pay for a font they probably already have in windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is **yes** (if you're using Typekit legitimately as part of your subscription to Adobe CC). Here are a couple of useful FAQs directly from the Typekit site:

**Can I use synced fonts for commercial projects or client work, such as creating business cards and logos?**

> Yes. You can create digital designs or print work for your own use or
>   for client projects. This includes generating a PDF, EPS file, or
>   bitmapped file such as a JPEG or PNG.

**Does my client need their own font license to use the designs?**

> No, not if you are creating documents that embed the font data, such
>   as a PDF, JPEG, or PNG. However, if your client needs to have the font
>   installed to edit your design, they will need their own license,
>   either through Typekit or as a perpetual desktop license purchase.

**Can I use the fonts to create products I will sell commercially, such as t-shirts, posters, or other printed merchandise?**

> Yes. You can use synced fonts for any kind of merchandise, whether
>   you’re designing a t-shirt for a friend or product packaging for a
>   client.

These are just a few answers that address your question. If you want a more in depth look into licensing fonts from Typekit, check out the rest of the [Typekit Licensing FAQs](https://helpx.adobe.com/typekit/using/font-licensing.html#sync-client) or the full legal [Services Agreement here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/legal/servicetou/Typekit-Services-Agreement-en_US-20161102.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

In my experience I believe Typekit is the place to go if you are in dire need for "the" font that will stand up for your brand or your client's brand.

Google fonts is still a class apart, but it is only in its nascent stage. In a few years time, it will be hosting a whole lot of fonts.

I would like you to check out these interesting reads.

1. [Typekit review](https://creativityincluded.com/reviews/typekit-review/)
2. [Typekit vs. Google Fonts](https://designshack.net/articles/typography/typekit-vs-google-fonts-pros-and-cons/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use them but you can't legally sell them or give them to others. Sounds a piece of bullshit, doesn't it?

But it isn't! If you use Typekit fonts (or any other copyrighted font) in writings or artwork files and sell or give yor work to somebody as a file, not as a printed paper, then very likely the file is not viewable "as -is" until there is the same typekit fonts are paid and installed also into your customer's machine. The fonts will be replaced by Arial and Times New Roman or something else that is available.

To avoid this you must find, what to do. This subject has been on the table several times. See at least these former discussions:

[How do I transfer use of Typekit fonts from one designer to another?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82782/how-do-i-transfer-use-of-typekit-fonts-from-one-designer-to-another?rq=1)

[Am I allowed to embed Typekit fonts directly into a website and host them myself?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36367/am-i-allowed-to-embed-typekit-fonts-directly-into-a-website-and-host-them-myself?rq=1)

[Font licensing warning when saving in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82281/font-licensing-warning-when-saving-in-illustrator/82299#82299)

Adobe has put a lot of effort to prevent people to distribute Adobe fonts or to use them without paying. That makes Typekit fonts invisible and inselectable in many applications. This is the case, if the application developer has not paid to Adobe get the fonts decrypted.

Typekit is hired. Any time the price can jump up or something important can be unavailable. It's a good practice to search passable free replacements for Typekit fonts - something that can be embedded into the arwork files. At least do not base anybody's brand appearance on Typekit without deep discussion about the risks.